# Langid detect language showing wrong result in #Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I need to detect the language of the strings stored below.

```
0                                                          nice
1                                                       Insane3
2                                                           NaN
3                                                @bertelsen1986
4                       20 or 30 mm rise on the Renthal Fatbar?
Name: Comments, dtype: object
```

Using `langid` module to detect the language of the comments stored in `df['Comments']`:

```
import langid
for row in df['Comments']:
  lang, log_prob = langid.classify(row)
  TM['Detected_Language']=lang
```

Below is the result, which is wrong:

```
    Comments                                          Detected_Language
0   nice                                                      zh
1   Insane3                                                   zh
2   ❤️                                                   zh
3   @bertelsen1986                                            zh
4   20 or 30 mm rise on the Renthal Fatbar?                   zh
```

The comments should return an 'en' instead.
(In the dataset, there are comments with other languages)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916600/text-language-detection-in-python

Comment: I have tried the post mentioned above before I ended up choosing the module `langid`. The `langdetect` has taken me over 12 hours to process only 25k rows.. @BEN_YO