# Replacing specific strings with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
    1-grams 2-grams             3-grams
0   game    first game         last you part
1   mama    last you           10 10 10
2   cool    naughty cat        us part ii
3   story   mama story         loved first game
4   save    10 10              first last you
... ... ... ...
926260  NaN NaN                game scenery improved
926261  NaN NaN                game scenery really
926262  NaN NaN                game scenes alone
926263  NaN NaN                game scenes cinematic
926264  NaN NaN                했는가 라는 생각이
```

I would like to work on each individual column (in particular 2-grams and 3-grams) to replace with NaN some rows which does not make sense, eg. `10 10` or `us part ii`.
I have though then to create three different datasets made by each individual column and replace rows which I am not interested it, then - eventually - concatenate them again.
However, I would like to know how to replace rows from 2-grams or 3-grams strings containing `10` or `us part ii` or `했는가 라는 생각이` with NaN values.

I would like to have something like:

```
    1-grams 2-grams             3-grams
0   game    first game         last you part
1   mama    last you           NaN
2   cool    naughty cat        NaN
3   story   mama story         loved first game
4   save    NaN                first last you
... ... ... ...
926260  NaN NaN                game scenery improved
926261  NaN NaN                game scenery really
926262  NaN NaN                game scenes alone
926263  NaN NaN                game scenes cinematic
926264  NaN NaN                NaN
```

where I replaced rows with my customised stopwords with NaN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916600/text-language-detection-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use applymap():

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN if '10' in str(x) or 'us part ii' in str(x) else x)
```

EDIT:
For generalized list of substrings:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN if any(substring in x for substring in excluded_list) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `isin`

```
df = df.mask(df.isin(['10 10','us part ii']))
```